# SAP B1 - Option Button- 'Unable to cast object System.String to type SAPbouiCOM.Item' Error

Tags: vb.net, casting, sapb1

I am writing a *vb.net* code in *Visual Studio* for an add on in *SAP B1*. Right now, I want to choose an option button and according to what the user chose, I want to take this value and send it to another function in another class. This action I want to make it right after the user press the **OK** button, so I am trying to do this in an event.

---

The code that I wrote for creating the options buttons:

```
Dim optBtn As SAPbouiCOM.OptionBtn
        'Dim oFrm As SAPbouiCOM.Form
        Dim oUserdatasource As SAPbouiCOM.UserDataSource

        oUserdatasource = oform2.DataSources.UserDataSources.Add("BD_resDS", SAPbouiCOM.BoDataType.dt_SHORT_TEXT, 1)

        'Option 1
        oItem = oform2.Items.Add("BD_rbRes", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_OPTION_BUTTON)
        oItem.Left = 155
        oItem.Top = 10
        oItem.Height = 16
        oItem.Width = 55
        optBtn = oItem.Specific
        optBtn.Caption = "Cheque"

        optBtn.DataBind.SetBound(True, , "BD_resDS")

        'Option 2
        oItem = oform2.Items.Add("BD_rbPost", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_OPTION_BUTTON)
        oItem.Left = 220
        oItem.Top = 10
        oItem.Height = 16
        oItem.Width = 55
        optBtn = oItem.Specific
        optBtn.Caption = "Cash"
        oItem.Visible = True
        optBtn = oItem.Specific
        optBtn.GroupWith("BD_rbRes")

        optBtn.DataBind.SetBound(True, , "BD_resDS")

        'Option 3
        oItem = oform2.Items.Add("BD_rbPost2", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_OPTION_BUTTON)
        oItem.Left = 280
        oItem.Top = 10
        oItem.Height = 16
        oItem.Width = 75
        optBtn = oItem.Specific
        optBtn.Caption = "Credit Card"
        oItem.Visible = True
        optBtn = oItem.Specific
        optBtn.GroupWith("BD_rbPost")
```

---

The code that I wrote in the event is this :

```
Public Sub SBO_Application_ItemEvent(ByVal FormUID As String, ByRef pVal As SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent, ByRef BubbleEvent As Boolean) Handles SBO_Application.ItemEvent
        Try
            Dim fInv As SAPbouiCOM.Form
            Dim omethod As SAPbouiCOM.Item
            Dim opaymeth As SAPbouiCOM.OptionBtn
            Dim paymeth As String

            'If pVal.ItemUID = "1" And pVal.EventType = SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_ITEM_PRESSED And pVal.BeforeAction = True And pVal.ActionSuccess = False And pVal.FormUID = "60006" Then

            'End If

            'Events of the Blanket Agreement form
            If (FormUID = "Choose") Then
                If (pVal.BeforeAction = False) Then
                    ' Click on Add Row
                    If (pVal.ItemUID = "1") And (pVal.EventType = SAPbouiCOM.BoEventTypes.et_ITEM_PRESSED) Then
                        fInv = SBO_Application.Forms.Item(FormUID)
                        omethod = fInv.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("BD_resDS").ValueEx

                        opaymeth = omethod.Specific

                        paymeth = opaymeth.Value.ToString()
                        SBO_Application.MessageBox(paymeth)

                        If paymeth <> "" And paymeth <> Nothing Then
                            Dim paym As New payment(SBO_Application, oCompany)
                            paym.pay(paymeth)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            'SBO_Application.MessageBox(er.Message)
            SBO_Application.MessageBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

---

Now, the error that I got in SAP B1 is:

> *Unable to cast object 'System.String'  to type 'SAPbouiCOM.Item'*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared 
 Dim omethod As SAPbouiCOM.Item

and assigning it to the string value 
omethod = fInv.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("BD_resDS").ValueEx

Declare string variable and assign value to it like

Dim tmpval as string =""
tmpval = fInv.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("BD_resDS").ValueEx

try this

Answer (score 0):

```
omethod = fInv.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("BD_resDS").ValueEx
```

.ValueEx seems to return a String, so I guess you just need to remove it

```
omethod = fInv.DataSources.UserDataSources.Item("BD_resDS")
```

Another fine example why you should always turn Option Strict ON ;)

Comment: I removed the `.ValueEx` as you said and I have now the error message: _'Unable to cast COM object of type 'SAPbouiCOM.UserDataSourceClass' to interface type 'SAPbouiCOM.Item'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{97702124-F229-4A00-FC584049EF9}' failed fue to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)). '_ Any idea what this is about ?

Comment: Also I don't know how to change my code after `Option Strict ON`, so I will let it as `OFF`